# Decoding Failed syntax error in Simple Products Generator extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used Simple Products Generator extension

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-products-generator.html

getting below screenshot error click on Generate Combination simple product
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change in IndexController.php, line no 113 
/app/code/community/WP/GenerateSimpleProducts/controllers

```
$selectedParams = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($data['spgOptions']);
```

with

```
$jsonstring = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $data['spgOptions']));
$selectedParams = json_decode($jsonstring, true);
```